# How to get the Rally TestCaseStepReferences for a Particular TestCase

Tags: rally

I have a requirement where I need to update the teststeps for a particular TestCase ex: **TC1020**

I have the following code which returns me the TestCaseResopnse

```
        QueryRequest testStepRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
        testStepRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("TC2006", "Name", "Steps")); //
        testStepRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=",
                "TC2006"));
        QueryResponse qresponse = restApi.query(testStepRequest);
```

**OUTPUT**

{
  "QueryResult": {
    "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
    "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
    "Errors": [

```
],
"Warnings": [
  "It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources."
],
"TotalResultCount": 1,
"StartIndex": 1,
"PageSize": 200,
"Results": [
  {
    "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
    "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
    "_ref": "https://us1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcase/17577048802",
    "_refObjectUUID": "cd9b3b44-9f56-40fc-a486-3149479786a9",
    "_objectVersion": "6",
    "_refObjectName": "Emp_DataCorrectness_AllUnmatched",
    "Name": "Emp_DataCorrectness_AllUnmatched",
    "Steps": {
      "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
      "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
      "_ref": "https://us1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TestCase/17577048802/Steps",
      "_type": "TestCaseStep",
      "Count": 5
    },
    "_type": "TestCase"
  }
]
```

}
}

I'ma able to get the Count as 5 which is expected. Now I want to get the TestCaseStep reference for all the teststep (ex:https://us1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcasestep/17577048860)
When i copy able URL browser I'm able to see the all 5 TestStepReference in the JSON response. Now I wanted to achieve it from the RestAPI.

Any help is highly Appreciated

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

In WSAPI 2.0, child collections of an object are no longer returned due to performance reasons, and it's necessary to make a follow-up query to obtain them. So you'll need to do something like the following:

```
JsonArray myTestCases = qresponse.getResults();

for (int i=0; i<myTestCases.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject testCase = myTestCases.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    QueryRequest testStepRequest = new QueryRequest(testCase.getAsJsonObject("Steps"));
    testStepRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("StepIndex", "Input", "ExpectedResult"));
    JsonArray testCaseSteps = restApi.query(testStepRequest).getResults();
    for (int j=0;j<testCaseSteps.size();j++){                       
        System.out.println(
            testCaseSteps.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("StepIndex").getAsString() + ": " + 
            testCaseSteps.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Input").getAsString() + ":" + testCaseSteps.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("ExpectedResult").getAsString());
    }
}
```

There's a more thorough explanation of this within this answer:

[Migrating from Rally API 1.43 to 2.0 - Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103056/migrating-from-rally-api-1-43-to-2-0-object-model/22103149#22103149)

Where the example is for obtaining a collection of TestCases from a TestSet, however the process is exactly analogous.